# How do I limit one connection per user for L2TP/IPSec using OpenSwan?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, openswan

I've successfully set up a VPN server with openswan, pppd, and xl2tpd on Ubuntu.

Everything works great, but I'm having trouble finding out how to only allow one VPN connection per user listed in the /etc/ppp/chap-secrets file?

Right now a user can have unlimited connections which is worrisome to me as I've shared access to the VPN with some friends but am worried they might keep spreading the username/password.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need **uniqueids=yes** in ipsec.conf